# How to search particular parameter in an array of JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing pretty simple thing here: getting Facebook news feed using their graph API. I'm receiving the json object and fetching it to the page. "Likes" come as an array of JSONs (obviously) like so:

data.likes:

```
{
    "count":2,
    "data":[
        {"name":"Jennifer Doe","id":"{user_id}"},
        {"name":"John Doe","id":"{user_id}"}
    ]
}
```

My goal is to know if the current user liked it or not - assume that I have current user's `user_id`. So, what's the simplest way to check if the current user is liked this post or not? 
I know I can set up for loop and go through each data, but that's not only inefficient, but also looks bad. I can also use `$.inArray()` and look for particular JSON object, but I want to be able to search by `user_id` only.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions come to my mind immediately:

-a for loop like this

```
for (jsonobj in data.likes.data){
  //scan each jsonobj for the user
}
```

-you could alternatively convert the JSON object in a string with

```
JSON.stringify(jsonobj)
```

and then search in it for the user id with some search method (for example 'search': http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp or also indexOf: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

if you need more details I can elaborate on this.

Comment: I like the second solution. It's pretty simple and I can write it in one line. Let's see what others will come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to just do a for loop, you can use the javascript eval method to create a generic method to return only the objects that you are looking for.

```
function searchArr(arr, field, val) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (eval('arr[i].' + field) == val) {
      output.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

and can be called this way with your data
`var matches = searchArr(data, 'id', userId);`

This method would work with any object...

Comment: "I know I can set up for loop and go through each data, but that's not only inefficient, but also looks bad." Thanks though

Comment: Then put the method in a utility javascript file and no one will ever see it... why the hangup on vanity?

Comment: forgot to mention that this code will be inside of template file. I'm also using MVC structure, so I want it to be organized well. and I am hoping there's simple way of doing it so that I don't have to create external function. In the worst case, I will just go with creating util class and functions. Any other ideas?